# LayerKit setting additional information to LYRIdentity

Tags: ios, objective-c, layerkit

I am using LayerKit with Atlas, it works perfectly without any issue but i'm curios that how can i set information like firstName, lastName, displayName, phoneNumber, etc to LYRIdentity? This properties are already available in LYRIdentity class but they are read only, authenticating user works perfectly but the problem is the authenticated user has only one property filled is userID which is as expected but how can i set additional properties? any suggestions will appreciable. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry it seems the api changed too much since I last used it. I deleted my answer

Comment: i glad that you tried to answer..thanks

Comment: FYI, the only option available just months ago was to handle yourself theses informations.

Comment: @Antzi can you help me with this?i mean handling manually isn't an option for me. any clues?

Comment: i have asked to layer support team today morning but no response yet

Comment: They are in the US, it might be too early for them.

Comment: yeah they are in SF :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had talk with support team and i'm answering my own question, this is a backend setup from where all these informations passed from, i read backend setup later so i was confused. including these values in [identity token](https://developer.layer.com/docs/ios/guides#step-3-post-the-nonce-and-generate-identity-token) from backend solves this.